# Как перенести несколько файлов на андроид устройство не включая его?

Tags: android, прошивка

Я решил установить прошивку на устройство и что-то пошло не так, не включается андроид система. Чтобы попробовать установить другую прошивку нужно перенести zip файл в одну папку на устройстве.
Слота для SD карты нет.

**Вопрос:** возможно ли туда, в устройство перенести файл, не включая андроид (через рекавери)?

- у меня есть комп (32 бит к сожелению, не 64 бит)

Comment: Про файлы не знаю, но вроде в некоторых рекавери видел некий sideload, который позволяет прошиться из zip, перекидываемому по usb на лету, без создания файла в папке телефона

Comment: Такие вещи сугубо индивидуальны, и тематика этого форума не про то. Лучше найдите на 4pda или подобном ресурсе тему по Вашему аппарату и спросите там.

Comment: (кстати ещё одна причина покупать телефоны с sd слотом:)